# How do I handle the reviewing and editing of LQ Answers for closed Questions?

Tags: discussion, review-beta

I have been spending a bit of time in the past few days in the new "[Review](https://askubuntu.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/stats)" tool after reading the stack **[feedback document](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta)**. Im also getting some positive comments from users who receive automated comments, so the tool has my thumbs up.

I have a query though (I couldn’t find the answer in the feedback document).

The are alot of answers appearing in the **Low Quality Post** section, and these answers are related to questions that have been closed.  Firstly, should they be appearing and if so what are the benefits of putting effort in to review them and take what action is needed?